# Undefined Is Not A Function (React Navigation Bottom Tab Navigator)

Tags: react-native

I am building bottom tabs navigator from react navigation v6 in react native mobile app but encountered an error.

```
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function

This error is located at:
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
    in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by tabNavigation)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by tabNavigation)
    in tabNavigation (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in authState (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in KFC(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

The Code Of Tab Navigator That I have written for tabs. I am using physical device for test:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Home from '../views/Home';
import Auth from '../views/Auth';
import Bucket from '../views/Bucket';
import Menu from '../views/Menu';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function tabNavigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="home">
        <Tab.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name="auth" component={Auth} />
        <Tab.Screen name="bucket" component={Bucket} />
        <Tab.Screen name="menu" component={Menu} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: The issue seems to be related to MaybeScreenContainer rather than the Bottom Tab Navigator.

Comment: Its core component of react navigation. It is not built by me

Answer (score 5):

Ran into the same error. Turns out, bottom tabs navigator also needs react-native-screens.

`yarn add react-native-screens` | `npm install react-native-screens` should do the trick. You may have to re-build or clear your cache as well.

Comment: This was immensely helpful. One thing to add here is after running `yarn add react-native-screens` I had to `cd` into the `ios` directory and run `pod install` and then we were good! Thanks!

Comment: Even after these two steps, if the issue still exists then you have to start the metro server again by clearing the cache using `yarn start --reset-cache`. It resolved me the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am using monorepo generated from `nx`. My fix was to just switch to this specific version:

`"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.9"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your screen one by one and you will find your trouble maker

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
//import Home from '../views/Home';
//import Auth from '../views/Auth';
//import Bucket from '../views/Bucket';
//import Menu from '../views/Menu';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function Dummy() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Dummy</Text>
    </View>
  );
}


export default function tabNavigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="home">
        <Tab.Screen name="home" component={Dummy} />
        <Tab.Screen name="auth" component={Dummy} />
        <Tab.Screen name="bucket" component={Dummy} />
        <Tab.Screen name="menu" component={Dummy} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: It still shows same error :(

Comment: Here are my packages:

Comment: "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.4",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "toastify-react-native": "^3.1.0"

Comment: Checkout this sample -> https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/tabs-dummy-sample

Comment: Yeah It is working here, so what should we do next?

Comment: I don't know. Delete caches/node_modules/watchman?

"Undefined Is Not A Function" is a hint that you just did an incorrect export, please verify you export your screens correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it had nothing to do with the navigation tab after all. My firebase upload was failing, but because react native has a hard time with async hooks it was sucking up the error instead of displaying it. On web you can run an async function in a hook, but apparently not with react native.  Once I turned the async function back into a .then function I was able to see the error.